# SSH broken after homedir permissions and hostname change on EC2-hosted Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04

I changed my instance's hostname using the `hostname` utility and then set it in `/etc/hostname` so that the new name survives reboot.

My main motivation was for differentiating between instances at the prompt using the `\h` 
format in `PS1`.

**EDIT**
I also changed permissions on my home directory. I made my home directory group writeable.

Now I can no longer SSH into the machine. The short of it is the error `Permission denied (publickey)`. Running `ssh -v`, the more verbose output is:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/dmitry/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dmitry/.ssh/ec2key.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Should I have done something after changing the hostname? Now I can't get into the instance! :(

Comment: "I made my home directory group writeable." - did you do that recursively, including the `.ssh` directory? If so, that makes OpenSSH daemon refuse your login using public key.

Comment: Actually, @gertvdijk, I did not! I left the `.ssh` read/writeable to me, only. It appears that SSH doesn't like it even when `~` is group writeable, please see my answer below!

Comment: good catch, good answer. Hope my comment was of any help anyway. :)

Comment: It turned out that I resolved the problem before your post, but couldn't answer my own question before waiting some time due to serverfault.com regulations on answering your own question (8 hours must elapse if your rating is low). Your comment would have definitely put me on the right track had I not resolved the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully the root mount was running on an EBS volume. So, I was able to debug this issue by stopping the instance and attaching the EBS volume to another instance I had running. I then examined `/var/log/auth.log`, which provided the useful information `ssh -v` was not providing. I noticed:

```
Nov 26 02:55:39 myhost sshd[1746]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/myuser
```

Indeed, SSH was not happy that I had given group write perms to my home directory, while `StrictModes` was set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

More information on this issue can found at http://recursive-design.com/blog/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/ or by searching the Web for `SSH StrictModes` or  `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory`.

Comment: How you solved the issue ? How can you change the permission if you don't have access to ssh ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have changed /etc/hosts too

Comment: I added `127.0.0.1  newhostname` to my `/etc/hosts` too, actually. Something else I should have changed?

Comment: added or changed? On a default Ubuntu install it's already in there, so you need to change it instead of adding to it.

Comment: I added it. As I recall, there was only `127.0.0.1 localhost` and some IPV6 enteries in the `/etc/hosts`, so nothing to edit really. It's not like there was a `127.0.0.1 oldhostname` entry.